# User input throws NegativeArraySizeException; same hardcoded (BOTH POSITIVE) number works

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, java.util.scanner, mergesort

I am currently working on an iterative merge sort, which asks the user for how many numbers to generate before sorting. If I input a number >10, I get the error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException", but if I hardcode the same exact number (both positive), the program works as intended. Why do I get this error, and how can I go about fixing it? Thank you for the help in advance.

**The demo file:**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MergeSortDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //int arraySize = 17;
        int arraySize = MergeSortAlgorithms.getArraySize(keyboard);
        int[] testArray = new int[arraySize];



        MergeSortAlgorithms.fillArray(testArray);
        MergeSortAlgorithms.printArray(testArray);
        MergeSortAlgorithms.mergeSort(testArray);
        MergeSortAlgorithms.printArray(testArray);
    }//ends main
}//ends class
```

**The iterative merge sort:**

```java
    public static void mergeSort(int arr[])
    {
        int n = arr.length;
        // For current size of subarrays to
        // be merged curr_size varies from
        // 1 to n/2
        int curr_size;

        // For picking starting index of
        // left subarray to be merged
        int left_start;


        // Merge subarrays in bottom up
        // manner. First merge subarrays
        // of size 1 to create sorted
        // subarrays of size 2, then merge
        // subarrays of size 2 to create
        // sorted subarrays of size 4, and
        // so on.
        for (curr_size = 1; curr_size <= n-1;
                    curr_size = 2*curr_size)
        {

            // Pick starting point of different
            // subarrays of current size
            for (left_start = 0; left_start < n-1;
                        left_start += 2*curr_size)
            {
                // Find ending point of left
                // subarray. mid+1 is starting
                // point of right
                int mid = left_start + curr_size - 1;

                int right_end = Math.min(left_start
                            + 2*curr_size - 1, n-1);

                // Merge Subarrays arr[left_start...mid]
                // & arr[mid+1...right_end]
                merge(arr, left_start, mid, right_end);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
    {
        int i, j, k;
        int n1 = m - l + 1;
        int n2 = r - m;

        /* create temp arrays */
        int L[] = new int[n1];
        int R[] = new int[n2];

        /* Copy data to temp arrays L[]
        and R[] */
        for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
            L[i] = arr[l + i];
        for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
            R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];

        /* Merge the temp arrays back into
        arr[l..r]*/
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        k = l;
        while (i < n1 && j < n2)
        {
            if (L[i] <= R[j])
            {
                arr[k] = L[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                arr[k] = R[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        /* Copy the remaining elements of
        L[], if there are any */
        while (i < n1)
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }

        /* Copy the remaining elements of
        R[], if there are any */
        while (j < n2)
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
```

**The array-related methods:**

```java
    public static int getArraySize(Scanner keyboard)
    {
        System.out.printf("How many numbers would you like to generate? \n(More Numbers = Longer Sort): ");
        int returnValue = keyboard.nextInt();

        return returnValue;
    }

    public static void fillArray(int[] array)
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            int randomNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 700 + 1);
            array[i] = randomNumber;
        }
    }
```

**The broken output (with array size of 17):**

```
How many numbers would you like to generate?
(More Numbers = Longer Sort): 17
241 272 539 456 242 571 333 28 292 426 7 595 191 162 1 542 394
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
        at MergeSortAlgorithms.merge(MergeSortAlgorithms.java:125)
        at MergeSortAlgorithms.mergeSort(MergeSortAlgorithms.java:112)
        at MergeSortDemo.main(MergeSortDemo.java:17)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**The same output, but 17 is the hardcoded array size:**

```
175 423 562 133 136 53 265 605 312 169 666 630 641 613 176 568 111
53 111 133 136 169 175 176 265 312 423 562 568 605 613 630 641 666
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**EDIT:**
After more testing, certain larger numbers actually work. For example, 25, 30, and 56 works as intended.

Comment: if this algorithm is throwing that Exception you can be sure there is an attempt to create an array with negative size. \check line 125 of `MergeSortAlgorithm`, most probably `n1` or `n2` is negative (calculation of `mid` is suspicious)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with taking input from the console. Instead, there is a Bug in your code.

```
int mid = left_start + curr_size - 1;
int right_end = Math.min(left_start + 2*curr_size - 1, n-1);
```

Consider above to lines. Whenever `left_start + 2*curr_size - 1` is sufficiently larger than `n-1`, the value of `right_end` will become smaller that `mid`.

In this case value of `n2` in merge() method becomes negative. Hence the error. Once you rectify this, you will solve the problem.

**UPDATE**
I have added a few `if` conditions. Here is the working code.

```
public static void mergeSort(int arr[])
{
    int n = arr.length;
    // For current size of subarrays to
    // be merged curr_size varies from
    // 1 to n/2
    int curr_size;

    // For picking starting index of
    // left subarray to be merged
    int left_start;


    // Merge subarrays in bottom up
    // manner. First merge subarrays
    // of size 1 to create sorted
    // subarrays of size 2, then merge
    // subarrays of size 2 to create
    // sorted subarrays of size 4, and
    // so on.
    for (curr_size = 1; curr_size <= n-1;
                curr_size = 2*curr_size)
    {

        // Pick starting point of different
        // subarrays of current size
        for (left_start = 0; left_start < n-1;
                    left_start += 2*curr_size)
        {
            // Find ending point of left
            // subarray. mid+1 is starting
            // point of right
            int mid = left_start + curr_size - 1;

            int right_end = Math.min(left_start
                        + 2*curr_size - 1, n-1);

            if(right_end<mid)
                right_end=mid;

            // Merge Subarrays arr[left_start...mid]
            // & arr[mid+1...right_end]
            merge(arr, left_start, mid, right_end);
        }
    }
}

public static void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - m;

    /* create temp arrays */
    int L[] = new int[n1];
    int R[] = new int[n2];

    /* Copy data to temp arrays L[]
    and R[] */
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        if(l+i<arr.length)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        if(l+j<arr.length)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];

    /* Merge the temp arrays back into
    arr[l..r]*/
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = l;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of
    L[], if there are any */
    while (i < n1 && i<n1 && k<arr.length)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    /* Copy the remaining elements of
    R[], if there are any */
    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

I feel you cam simplify the code, though.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code. It ran perfectly. Here is the output on console.

```
How many numbers would you like to generate? 
(More Numbers = Longer Sort): 17

[303, 394, 315, 436, 196, 212, 629, 139, 666, 519, 4, 182, 36, 108, 129, 490, 174]
[4, 36, 108, 129, 139, 174, 182, 196, 212, 303, 315, 394, 436, 490, 519, 629, 666]
```

No Exception :)

Comment: Try running the with different inputs. You will get the error eventually.